# vector subscript out of range when converting a char to int

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access a vector in c++, but it throws subscript out of range

```
string s = "itwqbtcdprfsuprkrjkausiterybzncbmdvkgljxuekizvaivszowqtmrttiihervpncztuoljftlxybpgwnjb";
    vector<int> result(s.size());
    result.resize(s.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        int d = s[i];
        result[d]++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `d < s.size()`? I think what you need is `std::map`.

Comment: Your third line is redundant btw.

Comment: @DimChtz d is not  < s.size(). What should I do to solve it ? I need to convert the string to an array and count it.

Comment: @DimChtz keep `d` below `s.size()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not what I said.

Comment: @DimChtz I probably meant to ping the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want with `int d = s[i];`, but `d` would be something like `'i'` which is unrelated to `result.size()`.

`'i'` is basically `105` in ASCII.

You probably want a `map`

```
const std::string s =
  "itwqbtcdprfsuprkrjkausiterybzncbmdvkgljxuekizvaivszowqtmrttiihervpncztuoljftlxybpgwnjb";
std::map<char, std::size_t> result;

for (char c : s)
{
   result[c]++;
}

for (const auto& p : result) {
    std::cout << "letter " << p.first << " appears " << p.second << "times\n"; 
}
```

If you want keep your vector, you may do something like:

```
const std::string s =
  "itwqbtcdprfsuprkrjkausiterybzncbmdvkgljxuekizvaivszowqtmrttiihervpncztuoljftlxybpgwnjb";
std::vector<std::size_t> result(26);

for (char c : s) {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
        result[c - 'a']++;
    }
}

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != result.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << "letter " << char('a' + ) << " appears " << result[i] << "times\n"; 
}
```

Comment: why its not possible to use a normal vector as an array and do result[c]++

Comment: can you answer my question please? why I can't use a vector as result[c]++ too ?

Comment: It is not impossible, but you use incorrect size. `'i'` is basically 105.

Comment: what does c-'a' means ?

Comment: @andre: `'a'` is the character 'a'. `c` is the variable representing the current character of the string. The diff `c - 'a'` would be `0` for `'a'`, `1` for `'b'`, .., `25` for `'z'`

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, `s.size ()` is the wrong value to resize `result` with. I would try something like

```
 vector<int> result(CHAR_MAX, 0);
```

and remove the call to `resize`, which is not so much redundant as it is actively pernicious.

Comment: If there's something you want me to add that I don't think will obscure the answer, I'll certainly add it.